# What is the technology to auto add a web form element?

Tags: javascript, dom, web

I am trying to learn web development, particularly on the aspect of dynamically adding form elements on the fly when a button is clicked.

For instance, I want to create a form with one text input box initially shown.  There will be a '+' button, which when clicked will make another input box appear.

Can someone tell me what keywords should I google for to learn more about the best technology to achieve such?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using any libraries? How are you validating and receiving the form's information?

Comment: @apaul34208 I haven't tried anything because I want to know what keywords I should google for in order to learn about this.

Comment: Just pointing out that your question is a little broad, you may get more useful answers if you narrow your scope to a specific case. Showing what you have written so far will narrow things down a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is what is used for this.  There are many, many, many JavaScript plugins and extensions that make it easier.   JQuery, AngularJS, ReactJS; just to name a few.

For instance, with jQuery, you simply do...

```
$document.ready(function(){
     $('#add').on('click', function(){
         $('#form').append('<input type="text">');
      )}
 })

 <div id='form'>
     <button id='add' value='Add Text Box' />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have an HTML button element whose "click" event triggers a piece of JavaScript code that then creates and inserts an HTML input element. JavaScript interacting with the HTML page it's running in involves the DOM (document object model), which is an API for page elements.

For events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers
For creating and inserting elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: Is there a library that does that or do I have to learn from scratch?

Comment: @Isaac There are many libraries for all kinds of things. But we're talking about a 2-step process here; "from scratch" doesn't really describe it.

Comment: To me, "from scratch" means not using a library (assuming there is a library for this sort of thing).